# Scheduler Design Help Needed

Tags: system-design

I am designing a system, which can have thousand of cron jobs. I am creating a UI where one can create cron job, and specify the interval in it. What system design you will suggest making it scalable?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a closer look on existing systems. Maybe they already fulfill your needs. Have a look at apache airflow (https://airflow.apache.org/),  Azkaban (https://azkaban.github.io/) or oozie (http://oozie.apache.org/).

If you really want to go for your own system please tell us a little more about the requirements.

Comment: I am a full-stack engineer, My Question is in terms of the backend infrastructure. So I am going to use the package called https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-differ to compare two HTML. There will be a user interface where the user will define the webpage URL and interval time where webpage changes will be checked. Let's assume we have 10k URL to check with different time intervals. I wanted to have a recommendation about the database or queuing system like rabbitmq i should use to make it scalable and fault tolerance.